# How to display ToolTip in Text Index and not on MouseCursor?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

is it possible that tooltip will locate in textindex and not in mouse cursor?

> note im working tooltip in text in windows form.

here's my sample tooltip:

```
 toolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
        toolTip1.InitialDelay = 1000;
        toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 500;
        //toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;
        toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "<)( Text ToolTip )(>";
        toolTip1.UseFading = true;
        toolTip1.UseAnimation = true;
```

parameter:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < keywords.Length; i++)
            {
                if (keywords[i] == token)
                {
                    // Apply alternative color and font to highlight keyword.        
                    HighlighType.keywordsType(rtb);

                        toolTip1.Show("this is a keyword", rtb); //&
                        break;
                }
            }
```

when a keyword will be type in richtextbox, something like for example "as" ,tooltip will appear but in a MOUSEcursor only , i want it near textindex .

is that possible? thanks a lot!

Comment: it's easier that you search for something already implemented out there (seems not so easy topic).

Comment: its just becoming hard sir because tooltip was for tools but i make it for text just like in actual code-editor

Comment: just like this sir: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464085/WinForms-RichTextBox-ToolTip-like-Visual-Studios but i dunno what specifically event he use, if its a mousemove or what .and how to do it when you mouseover it on text :/ .sorry newbie here :(

Comment: anyone? pls ? ..........

Answer (score 0):

you need to combine [`ToolTip.Show (String, IWin32Window, Point)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44atyhsa.aspx) Method with [`GetPostitionFromCharIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getpositionfromcharindex%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

so you get the `Point` of the text from `GetPostitionFromCharIndex` and pass it to the `ToolTip.Show`

Comment: how to do it sir? what specific code would i do in combining those? thanks sir

Comment: @Elegiac: calling GetPositionFromCharIndex you get a client coordinate of the character you want inside control, after show tooltip exactly on that coordiante.

Comment: @Tigran can you pls show me how to do it? sorry newbie here -_- . i always get bug in tooltip codes since tooltips are made for tools and not for text -_-

Comment: @Elegiac: var pointOnControl = GetPositionFromCharIndex(charIndexInText); toolTipShow("Wraning!", textControl, pointOnControl); Something like this.